# Convolution example

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

> Let $f(x)$ be an even function on $(-\infty , \infty)$ and let $g(x) = \sin(ax)$, $a >0$.
>
> Show that
>   $$(f \ast g)(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)\sin(a(x-t))\,dt= \sin(ax)\hat{f}(a).$$

I end up with $$\sin(ax)\hat{f}(a) - e^{-iax}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\sin(at)\,dt.$$ The last part goes two zero?

Also, I used angle expansion. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Your second integral is zero because $f(x)\sin(ax)$ is an odd function of $x$ (product of even with odd)

Comment: You wrote: (f $\ast g)(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)sina(x-t)dt$= $sin(ax)\hat{f}(a)$.That does not seem right to me. Is there a typo or editing error there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $f$ is an even function you know that $f(-t) = f(t)$.  Additionally, $\sin$ is an odd function, i.e. $\sin(-at) = -\sin(at)$.  Therefore, $f(-t)\sin(-at) = -f(t)\sin(at)$, and so

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)\sin(at)\,dt &= \int_{-\infty}^{0}f(t)\sin(at)\,dt + \int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)\sin(at)\,dt\\
&= -\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)\sin(at)\,dt + \int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)\sin(at)\,dt\\
&=0.
\end{align*}
$$